# Display custom post type posts and meta data within the_content filter

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, thumbnails

I am using this in my mu-plugins.php file//

```
function new_default_content($content) {
global $post;
if ($post->post_type == 'textures') {
$content .='<li>
<figure>
   <?php the_post_thumbnail('thummy'); ?>
   <figcaption>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<span>Cool stuff brah.</span>

<?php 
 if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
$large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >View Full Image</a>'; }?>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </li>';
}
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'new_default_content');
```

and in my page template I used `<?php the_content(); ?>` to display everything.

**UPDATE//**
*Full Page Template code*

```
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
<div id="left-content">
    <?php get_sidebar('two');?> 
</div>

<div id="right-content">
    <h1><?php wp_title(''); ?></h1>

    <ul class="grid cs-style-3">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
</div><!--right-content-->
</div><!--container-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But I am recieving this error//
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/xxx/public_html/domain.com/testing/wp-content/mu-plugins/must-use.php on line 15**

I am trying this method of displaying content because I want to use the *WP-Members*  plugin, and I realized that the plugin will only work for content within `the_content()`.

So my question is how can I fix the code I posted above to display the title, thumbnail, links etc the correct way?

Comment: Check for quotes or braces if you have missed any.

Comment: @Pranita I'm honestly not familiar with wordpress filters, so I am not sure how the code is suppose to look. But thanks.

Comment: I have replied corrected code. Check if you get error with that code.

Answer (score 2):

```
function new_default_content($content) {
global $post;
if ($post->post_type == 'textures') {
$content .='<li>';
$content .='<figure>';
$content .= the_post_thumbnail('thummy');
$content .= '<figcaption>';
$content .= '<h3>';
$content .= the_title();
$content .= '</h3>';
$content .= '<span>Cool stuff brah.</span>';

 if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
    echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >View Full Image</a>'; 
 }
        $content .= '</figcaption>';
    $content .= '</figure>';
$content .= '</li>';
}
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'new_default_content');
```

Just try this code. If you still get same error we'll check.

Comment: I tried the code provided, thanks very much for your help! But the issue remains :/ I updated my post and added the code within my template page file. When I am logged out of WP the registration form and login form is displayed perfectly. But when I sign in and view the Page I marked for members only, the content area is blank. I can post screenshots or paste whatever code is needed if you are willing to continue helping me.

Comment: place the above function in functions.php and if you can just send a link of your site. We'll check what exactly is going wrong. and also create a dummy user for test.

Comment: I originally had the code in mu-plugins.php but I followed your instructions and added it to functions.php, and yet the issue still occurs. I will post the link inside of my question so I am able to delete when this issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

**FOUND A SOLUTION**
I remembered that you can add content inside of shortcodes.
So I created my own shortcode `[textures_content]`

Then used the code pasted below to display the content within `<?php the_content(); ?>` function//

```
add_shortcode( 'textures_content', 'textures_shortcode' );
function textures_shortcode( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'textures',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
    ) );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('thummy'); ?>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
                            $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
                            echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >View Full Image</a>'; }?>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
    }
}
```

Now the Members only plugin works as expected and the blocked content is displayed once logged in :)